# how to extract digits and letters

Tags: c#, token

how can i make a function that extracts digits and letters from tokens,i am trying to work on a lexical analyzer in c sharp which extracts variables datatypes liberaries  from a cpp file
i want my function to extract digits and letters i have managed to make functions that extract variables ,datatypes n libraries

for example i want a combination of these two functions

```
bool IsDigit(char ch)
{
    return (ch >='0' && ch <= '9');
}

bool IsAlpha(char ch)
{
    return (ch >='a' && ch <= 'z'|| ch>'A '&& ch<'Z');

}
```

any ideas??

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: _for example i want a combination of these two functions_ : `bool IsDigitOrAlpha(char ch) { return IsDigit(ch) || IsAlpha(ch); }`?

Comment: Have a look at [`Char.IsDigit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh.aspx)

Comment: im trying to research on a question i posted yesterday you can take a look at it maybe it will be more clearer... this is the link.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274890/how-to-identify-digits-and-expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:-

```
 Match match = regex.Match("10ABCD");
 string letter = match.Groups["letter"].Value;
  int number = int.Parse(match.Groups["number"].Value);
```

or try a regular expression:-

```
 ((?<number>\d+)(?<letter>[a-zA-Z])|(?<letter>[a-zA-Z])(?<number>\d+))
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do this:

```
private bool IsAlphaNumeric(string letter)
{
     return Regex.IsMatch(letter, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first off, you should be doing this on `IsAlpha` (notice the extra brackets)

```
((ch >='a' && ch <= 'z')||(ch>'A '&& ch<'Z'))
```